# SSRS - Child group position / subreport?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I've got a report with parent and child groups as you can see below, which work fine.[image]

Results look like this and as you can see column from Initiative Name to Reasons for Overall status are the same, therefore I would like to group these as well, but I can't figure it out. When I add a new child group (Milestone Name), it adds column right after the Initiative name column, which I don't want to.  [image]

The ideal results should look like this:
[image]

Could you advise me how can I achieve that, please? I've also tried to use subreport, but I wasn't able to make it work either.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the columns to the grouping in your outer group `(MissionCritical)`.

Once this is done you will probably (this is from memory) need to insert a row under the top row (Right-click, insert row, inside-group, below).

This will give you two rows for the outer group.

Then copy / paste the contents of each column affected (the light blue ones I guess) and paste them into the new row. You can then remove them from the `details` row.

This should give you what you want. If not, let me know and I'll setup a sample to demonstrate.